# Graphics.DrawLine, AccessViolation, Visual Studio IDE

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, ide, gdi+, vb.net-2010

Having difficulty with Graphics.DrawLine Creating an Access Violation.  Tried Restarting VS2010/the computer, Repairing the Framework, windows update, and looking for any kind of patches or patches to remove.  Nothing seems to get rid of it.  Even the sample on the MS site crashes with the error.  Not sure what to look for to fix it.  It used to work so I'm betting its a bad patch somewhere, just not sure which.  Currently running under windows XP.

Update 1: Updated the code to cross reference with the API.  DrawLineInt uses the Framework, DrawLineInt2 use the API commands.  They both violate on the DrawLine Function.  Throwing this sample into VB6 does not create this problem.

Update 2: Apparently, if the VS studio environment settings are set to C++ this bug doesn't occur.  Resetting settings and putting it back to "Visual Basic" causes this bug to reappear.  Uninstalling/Installing VS2010 and the .NET frameworks did nothing to fix this.  Running a built executable does not cause a crash in the executable, but can crash VS...hmmm..?

Update 3: Tried other drawing methods, and added a call trace below.  Apparently any methods that use a PEN cause the exception, but the ones with a BRUSH do not.  When tracing inside the copy_32 method the pointer to the draw space is invalid (either 0x0 or 0xBAADF00D).  This also makes a GroupBox useless as it uses the same draw routines.

Sample Code...

```vb
Public Class Form1
Public Sub DrawLineInt2(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
    'Misc
    Dim Ret As GpStatus

    ' Create pen. 
    Dim blackPen As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
    Dim blackbrush As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
    Dim c As Int32 = &HFF000000

    Ret = GdipCreateSolidFill(c, blackbrush)
    'Ret = GdipCreatePen1(c, 10, GpUnit.UnitPixel, blackPen)
    Ret = GdipCreatePen2(blackbrush, 10, GpUnit.UnitPixel, blackPen)

    ' Create coordinates of points that define line. 
    Dim x1 As Integer = 100
    Dim y1 As Integer = 100
    Dim x2 As Integer = 500
    Dim y2 As Integer = 125

    ' Draw line to screen.
    Dim graphics As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero

    'Ret = GdipCreateFromHDC(e.Graphics.GetHdc, graphics)
    Ret = GdipCreateFromHWND(Me.Handle, graphics)

    'System.AccessViolationException here
    Ret = GdipDrawLineI(graphics, blackPen, x1, y1, x2, y2)

    'Here Also
    'Ret = GdipDrawRectangleI(graphics, blackPen, x1, y1, x2, y2)

    'Here as well
    'Ret = GdipDrawArcI(graphics, blackPen, x1, y1, x2, y2, 15, 20)

    'No problems with this line
    'Ret = GdipFillRectangleI(graphics, blackbrush, x1, y1, x2, y2)


    Ret = GdipDeletePen(blackPen)
    Ret = GdipDeleteBrush(blackbrush)
    Ret = GdipDeleteGraphics(graphics)

    'e.Graphics.ReleaseHdc()
End Sub

Public Sub DrawLineInt(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
    ' Create pen. 
    Dim blackPen As New Pen(Color.Black, 3)
    ' Create coordinates of points that define line. 
    Dim x1 As Integer = 100
    Dim y1 As Integer = 100
    Dim x2 As Integer = 500
    Dim y2 As Integer = 100

    ' Draw line to screen.
    Try
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, x1, y1, x2, y2)
    Catch
    End Try
    blackPen.Dispose()
End Sub
Private Sub Form1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    'DrawLineInt(e)
    DrawLineInt2(e)
End Sub


Private Enum GpStatus As Int32
    Ok = 0
    GenericError = 1
    InvalidParameter = 2
    OutOfMemory = 3
    ObjectBusy = 4
    InsufficientBuffer = 5
    NotImplemented = 6
    Win32Error = 7
    WrongState = 8
    Aborted = 9
    FileNotFound = 10
    ValueOverflow = 11
    AccessDenied = 12
    UnknownImageFormat = 13
    FontFamilyNotFound = 14
    FontStyleNotFound = 15
    NotTrueTypeFont = 16
    UnsupportedGdiplusVersion = 17
    GdiplusNotInitialized = 18
    PropertyNotFound = 19
    PropertyNotSupported = 20
End Enum

Private Enum GpUnit As Int32  ' aka Unit
    UnitWorld      ' 0 -- World coordinate (non-physical unit)
    UnitDisplay    ' 1 -- Variable -- for PageTransform only
    UnitPixel      ' 2 -- Each unit is one device pixel.
    UnitPoint      ' 3 -- Each unit is a printer's point, or 1/72 inch.
    UnitInch       ' 4 -- Each unit is 1 inch.
    UnitDocument   ' 5 -- Each unit is 1/300 inch.
    UnitMillimeter ' 6 -- Each unit is 1 millimeter.
End Enum

Private Declare Function GdipDrawLine Lib "gdiplus.dll" (ByVal graphics As IntPtr, ByVal pen As IntPtr, ByVal x1 As Single, ByVal y1 As Single, ByVal x2 As Single, ByVal y2 As Single) As GpStatus
Private Declare Function GdipDrawLineI Lib "gdiplus.dll" (ByVal graphics As IntPtr, ByVal pen As IntPtr, ByVal x1 As Int32, ByVal y1 As Int32, ByVal x2 As Int32, ByVal y2 As Int32) As GpStatus

Private Declare Function GdipCreatePen1 Lib "gdiplus.dll" (ByVal color As Int32, ByVal Width As Single, ByVal unit As GpUnit, ByRef pen As IntPtr) As GpStatus
Private Declare Function GdipCreatePen2 Lib "gdiplus.dll" (ByVal brush As IntPtr, ByVal Width As Single, ByVal unit As GpUnit, ByRef pen As IntPtr) As GpStatus
Private Declare Function GdipDeletePen Lib "gdiplus.dll" (ByVal pen As Int32) As GpStatus

Private Declare Function GdipCreateSolidFill Lib "gdiplus" (ByVal argb As Int32, ByRef brush As IntPtr) As GpStatus
Private Declare Function GdipDeleteBrush Lib "gdiplus" (ByVal brush As IntPtr) As GpStatus

Private Declare Function GdipFillRectangleI Lib "gdiplus" (ByVal graphics As IntPtr, ByVal brush As IntPtr, ByVal x As Int32, ByVal y As Int32, ByVal Width As Int32, ByVal Height As Int32) As GpStatus
Private Declare Function GdipDrawRectangleI Lib "gdiplus" (ByVal graphics As IntPtr, ByVal pen As IntPtr, ByVal x As Int32, ByVal y As Int32, ByVal Width As Int32, ByVal Height As Int32) As GpStatus

Private Declare Function GdipDrawArcI Lib "gdiplus" (ByVal graphics As IntPtr, ByVal pen As IntPtr, ByVal x As Int32, ByVal y As Int32, ByVal Width As Int32, ByVal Height As Int32, ByVal startAngle As Single, ByVal sweepAngle As Single) As GpStatus


Private Declare Function GdipCreateFromHDC Lib "gdiplus.dll" (ByVal hdc As IntPtr, ByRef graphics As IntPtr) As GpStatus
Private Declare Function GdipCreateFromHWND Lib "gdiplus.dll" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByRef graphics As IntPtr) As GpStatus
Private Declare Function GdipDeleteGraphics Lib "gdiplus" (ByVal graphics As IntPtr) As GpStatus
```

End Class

The Exception Call stack

> GdiPlus.dll!ScanOperation::Copy_32()  + 0x14 bytes
>       GdiPlus.dll!EpAlphaBlender::Blend()  + 0x58 bytes
>       GdiPlus.dll!EpScanGdiDci::DrawScanRecords_Dci()  + 0x1de bytes
>       GdiPlus.dll!EpScanGdiDci::ProcessBatch_Dci()  + 0x181 bytes 
>       GdiPlus.dll!EpScanGdiDci::EmptyBatch()  + 0x6b5ab bytes 
>       GdiPlus.dll!EpScanGdiDci::End()  + 0x1e bytes
>       GdiPlus.dll!EpScanBufferNative::~EpScanBufferNative()  + 0x18 bytes
>       GdiPlus.dll!DpDriver::StrokePath()  + 0x20a bytes
>       GdiPlus.dll!DriverMulti::StrokePath()  + 0x6c bytes 
>       GdiPlus.dll!GpGraphics::DrvStrokePath()  + 0x2a bytes
>       GdiPlus.dll!GpGraphics::RenderDrawPath()  + 0xa3 bytes
>       GdiPlus.dll!GpGraphics::DrawLines()  + 0xe8 bytes
>       GdiPlus.dll!GpGraphics::DrawLine()  + 0x45 bytes
>       GdiPlus.dll!_GdipDrawLine@24()  + 0x8e bytes
>       GdiPlus.dll!_GdipDrawLineI@24()  + 0x37 bytes
>       [External Code] 
>     WindowsApplication2.exe!WindowsApplication2.Form1.DrawLineInt2(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e) Line 30 + 0x17 bytes  Basic

The Exception it drops...

> System.AccessViolationException was unhandled   Message=Attempted to
>   read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other
>   memory is corrupt.   Source=System.Drawing   StackTrace:   at
>   System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipDrawLineI(HandleRef
>   graphics, HandleRef pen, Int32 x1, Int32 y1, Int32 x2, Int32 y2)   at
>   System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawLine(Pen pen, Int32 x1, Int32 y1, Int32
>   x2, Int32 y2)   at
>   WindowsApplication1.Form1.DrawLineInt(PaintEventArgs e) in
>   C:\Documents and Settings\FF\Local Settings\Application Data\Temporary
>   Projects\WindowsApplication1\Form1.vb:line 15   at
>   WindowsApplication1.Form1.Form1_Paint(Object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
>   in C:\Documents and Settings\FF\Local Settings\Application
>   Data\Temporary Projects\WindowsApplication1\Form1.vb:line 19   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e,
>   Int16 layer)   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr
>   hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)   at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[]
>   commandLine)   at WindowsApplication1.My.MyApplication.Main(String[]
>   Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81   at
>   System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[]
>   args)   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()   at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)   at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   ignoreSyncCtx)   at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)   at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Comment: I've seen this call stack before, the reason is as yet undiagnosed.  But this code certainly has a flaw, it is going to leak GDI handles badly if the Paint event fires a lot.  You will need to use the Using statement to properly dispose the pen.

Comment: Modified the sample, and Added an API version which seems to exhibit the same problem. All the RETs come back as "ok".  This problem doesn't show up if the code was run in VB6 though.

Comment: Updated with more observations, simplified the example coding to be more explicit.

Comment: The sample code just doesn't reproduce any errors.

Comment: Updated the code again, apparently functions with 'brush' objects work fine.  Just functions with 'Pen' objects have issues.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution that worked for me.  Either upgrade or rollback your video drivers.

I have a Radeon HD6950 with driver version 9.00.100.10.  When I rolled back the driver to version 8.980.0.0. the "gdipdrawline" errors stopped.  This means all the controls that used the function now also work.  I can confirm working the GroupBox and the DataGridView as they previously crashed with the same or similar call stacks.